# Determining length of a subset of an oracle table with LONG RAW

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am doing a space consumption analysis on a table saved in Oracle DB, used by an external application. Doesn't really have access to the underlying DB.
How to determine a length of a subset of oracle table with LONG RAW. Will it be a percentage of the total length of the table. For E.g. if total space occupied by the oracle table is 1 GB with total records of 1,000,0000 and If I want to know how much space is used by 200,000 record on the basis of a selection condition. 
Will be it as simple as direct percentage of the number of records to the able space ?
Please enlighten.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Do you have access to the user who owns this table? What dows `SELECT owner FROM all_tables WHERE table_name='MY_TABLE';` say? (Pls replace MY_TABLE with the name of your table)

Comment: hello! Unfortunately I don't have direct access to the underlying database. I am on a ABAP stack or SAP system.

Comment: You tagged the question with 'oracle-sqldeveloper'. Can you execute SQL?

Comment: Yes I can! The problem is the limited visibility to the database...!

Comment: Hence wondered if there is a calculations or formula... Which can determine the size of the table subset

Comment: Btw... I got the user for the table which I was referring to...

Comment: Do you  have a specific sql query which will help me find the information  I need.... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Oracle keeps a lot of information about the space that is used for tables, indexes and stuff. All of those things that occupy space live in a **segment**, which can be found in the data dictionary view `USER_SEGMENTS`:

```
CREATE TABLE t (i NUMBER, r LONG RAW);
INSERT INTO t (i) VALUES (1);

SELECT segment_type, bytes, blocks FROM user_segments WHERE segment_name='T';
SEGMENT_TYPE  BYTES    BLOCKS
TABLE         65536    8
```

So, a nearly empty table occupies 8 blocks of 8K, which are together 64 kilobytes large. If you insert some `LONG RAW` test data, the size increase accordingly:

```
INSERT INTO t
SELECT object_id, hextoraw(lpad('AA',1000,'AA')) 
  FROM all_objects 
 WHERE ROWNUM <= 10000;

SELECT segment_type, bytes, blocks FROM user_segments WHERE segment_name='T';
SEGMENT_TYPE  BYTES    BLOCKS
TABLE         6291456  768
```

The most precise measurement would be to create a test table with your select condition and measure it:

```
CREATE TABLE testtable NOLOGGING TABLESPACE my_scratch_ts AS 
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_column = ...;
```

If the length of the `LONG RAW`s is evenly distributed, you can use the percentage approach you mentioned.

The datatype `LONG` and `LONG RAW` is a real pain to work with, which is why Oracle recommends not to use it for new projects. You need to run queries in PL/SQL to determine the actual size:

```
DECLARE
  s NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  FOR c IN (SELECT r, -- get the long raw column to measure it's length
                   vsize(i) as v -- get the size of the other column(s)
              FROM t 
             WHERE i between 1700 and 1800) -- example for your selection
  LOOP
    s := s + c.v; -- add the lengths other columns
    s := s + utl_raw.length(c.r); -- add the length of the long raw
  END LOOP;
  dbms_output.put_line('total size of selection = '||s||' bytes');
END;
/
```

When you switch on `DBMS_OUTPUT` in SQL Developer it will say something like:

```
total size = 24000 bytes
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. Though I didn't perform the same set of steps, it did give me an idea to get the exact space occupied by the table. But if I had full access to the DB, I would definitely gone by this approach. Thanks and marking this as the answer/helpful.